# How to perform lookup on certain condition

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible in MongoDb to perform lookup, but only on certain condition? I Need to get events form my MongoDb and only when event has related bet added by certain user - I'd like to add bet to collection.

Firstly, I used Match operator and $lookup to get bets related to event, but the problem is I need to define second condition - user identifier of bet has to be the same as the value of external parameter (userId).

Then I need to add only one result, not a collection - that's why I used $project. Please help.

My code goes here:

```
            db.collection('events').aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        'isDeleted': false,
                        'leagueId': ObjectID(leagueId)
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "bets",
                        localField: "_id",
                        foreignField: "eventId",
                        as: "bets"
                    },
                },
                { 
                    $project: { 
                        _id: true,
                        home: true,
                        guest: true,
                        description: true,
                        result: true,
                        resultHome: true,
                        resultGuest: true,
                        startDate: true,
                        type: true,
                        specialPoints: true,
                        leagueStage: true,
                        createdDate: true,
                        updatedDate: true,
                        isDeleted: true,
                        isCalculated: true,
                        leagueId: true,
                        bet: { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$bets", 0 ] } 
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't have a condition in the `$lookup`. But you can do the following.
After the lookup you have an array of `bets`. You can use `$unwind`.
This way you have a flat representation of your array. That means if you have one document with two array entries, then 2 documents will be created with the same fields and names only the array will differ.

Then you can use `$match` again to filter out only the one you want. Then you wouldn't need to use `$project`, unless you want to modify your document.

So your aggregation pipeline would look something like this:

```
db.getCollection('events').aggregate([{
        $match: {
            'isDeleted': false,
            'leagueId': ObjectID(leagueId)
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "bets",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "eventId",
            as: "bets"
        },
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$bets"
    },
    {
        // match here again to only get the bet you need
    }
])
```

Hope it helps.